# How to render GLKViewController with iphone camera

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have a GLKViewController which renders a cube and also a transformations class which helps it get scaled, moved or rotated. This view controller use the device data as well to rotate the cube. I want to place this cube on iOS camera. Please help.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, rickster's answer worked for me. Have a look of sample code mentioned in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AVCapture` classes from the AVFoundation framework to get video from the camera, and the `CVOpenGLESTextureCache` class to get camera frames into OpenGL ES textures. Once you have such a texture, use it like any other — call `glBindTexture` and issue a draw call. Camera data comes in biplanar YUV format, so you'll need a shader program that reads the Y and UV textures and converts them to an RGB output while drawing.

Apple's [GLCameraRipple sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrates all of the above.